# Why is this function not working but not displaying errors in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, inputstream

If I comment out the two for loops, the program will run fine (given I adjust a variable or two). However, when I compile and run in Eclipse it just sits and does not have any overflow errors or anything else. The file is a text file that I am trying to filter out things based off which lines have a * character in them.

```
  public List<String> readFile1(File file) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

    //Construct BufferedReader from InputStreamReader
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    String line = null;
    String checker = null;
    int whereMenuItemIs = 0;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if(!line.startsWith("\u0009")) {
            for(int i=0; i<getListFromFile("C:/IRT", "bios.txt").size(); i++)
            {
                if(getListFromFile("C:/IRT", "bios.txt").get(i).contains(line))
                {
                    i = whereMenuItemIs;
                }
            }
            for(int j=whereMenuItemIs+1; j<getListFromFile("C:/IRT", "bios.txt").size(); j++)
            {
                if(readFile1(file).contains(getListFromFile("C:/IRT", "bios.txt").get(j)))
                {
                    System.out.println("it got here");
                }
                else
                {
                    checker= checker + getListFromFile("C:/IRT", "bios.txt").get(j);
                }
            }
        if(checker.contains("\u0009*")){

        }
            list.add(line);
        }
    }

    br.close();
    return list;
}
```

Comment: It just sits and never exits the loop? Try throwing a print statement in there to see what it keeps reading

Comment: It gets caught here : for(int i=0; i<getListFromFile("C:/IRT", "bios.txt").size(); i++)
          {
           if(getListFromFile("C:/IRT", "bios.txt").get(i).contains(line))
           {
            System.out.println("firstIf");
            i = whereMenuItemIs;
           }
          }

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be rereading the file every time you enter the loop. Just read it at the top and dump it into an array

Comment: if I comment out the first for, I get a stack overflow error. If you look, the function eventually makes a list. Should I just make a second function the removes list items?

Comment: Why would you assume that if there are no errors then it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While imbedding functions inside of other statements works in many places, in others it won't.

When the compiler sets up for loops and similar constructs, it does a lot of work.  I think your loop value for i, calculated as getListFromFile("C:/IRT", "bios.txt").size(); is alot different than what you expect.

Try printing out that answer--getListFromFile("C:/IRT", "bios.txt").size(); or getting it outside the loop, assign it to a variable and then using it.  If the equation does yield a file size, it may be resetting itself on every loop.

Also, you should not be reading the file 5 times in a program.

Answer (score 0):

Your line :

```
i = whereMenuItemIs;
```

should be :

```
whereMenuItemIs = i;
```

Comment: Thank you all. Now it is executing (after a long time because of all of the loops. Essentially, I am giving this function a list with SATA Emulation and EFI Boot Order from this piece of text:SATA Emulation
 IDE
 RAID
 *AHCI
EFI Boot Order
 USB Floppy/CD
 USB Hard Drive
 ATAPI CD-ROM Drive
 Other                                                                                              and it is supposed to comb out EFI Boot Order because what is proceeding it does not have a *

Comment: `public List<String> getOptions(List<String> menuOne) throws IOException
 {
  List<String> menuOneRevised = menuOne;
  String checker = "";
  for(int i=0; i<getListFromFile("C:/IRT", "bios.txt").size(); i++)
        {
   for(int j=0; j<menuOne.size(); j++)
   {
    if(getListFromFile("C:/IRT", "bios.txt").get(i).contains(menuOne.get(j)))
    {
     for(int k=i+1; k<getListFromFile("C:/IRT", "bios.txt").size(); k++)
     {
      if(!menuOne.contains(getListFromFile("C:/IRT", "bios.txt").get(k)))`

Comment: `{
       checker = checker + getListFromFile("C:/IRT", "bios.txt").get(k);
       }
     }
     if(!checker.contains("*"))
     {
      menuOneRevised.remove(j);
     }
      
    }
   }
        }
  
  return menuOneRevised;`